# Show that equation $u_x + u_t =0$ has no solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I need to prove that the Partial Differential Equation $u_x + u_t = 0 $ where $u(x,t) =  x$ on $x^2 + t^2 =  1$ has no solution.

I solved this equation with method of characteristics and got one value of $u(x,t)$ as

$u(x,t) =  x - t + \sqrt{1-(u(x,t))^2}$ ,

how do I show that this is not the solution of given equation.

Any hints?

Comment: What's $u^2$?   is that a recursively defined function?

Comment: Yeah I got the solution as an implicit equation, I have edited the question now

Comment: Just move $x-t$ to the other side and take square?

Comment: Show that function $u$ is constant along the lines $x(t) = C - t$. Assume a solution exist and try to derive a contradiction wrt the initial condition: $u=x$ on the circle $x^2+t^2=1$ (e.g. consider a line that intersects the circle in two points and ask yourself what the function value is at those points).

Answer (score -1):

I agree with you for this particular solution :
$$u =  x - t + \sqrt{1-u^2} \tag 1$$
There is another particular solution :
$$u =  x - t - \sqrt{1-u^2} \tag 2$$
In fact the solution is made of the union of the two branches which is described by the implicit equation :
$$\boxed{2u^2-2(x-t)u+(x-t)^2-1=0}\tag 3$$
CHECKING :
$$4uu_x-2u-2(x-t)u_x+2(x-t)=0 \quad\implies\quad u_x=\frac{u-x+t}{2u-x+t}$$
$$4uu_t+2u-2(x-t)u_t-2(x-t)=0 \quad\implies\quad u_t=\frac{-u+x-t}{2u-x+t}$$
$$u_x+u_t=\frac{u-x+t}{2u-x+t}+\frac{-u+x-t}{2u-x+t}=0\quad\text{thus eq.}(3)\text{ satisfies the PDE}.$$
And putting $u=x$ into Eq.$(3)$ :
$$2x^2-2(x-t)x+(x-t)^2-1=0 \quad \to\quad x^2+t^2=1 \quad\text{thus the condition is satisfied.}$$
This seems contradictory with the assumption that there is no solution. Why ?

Comment:

According to Eq.(3) the solution $u(x,t)$ is not a one-to-one function but is a multivalued function. As a consequence one have to discuss about the wording of the problem.

- If the question is "Has the PDE and condition a solution on the form of a one-to-one function? ", the answer is NO because the condition is not satisfied on the WHOLE circle $x^2+t^2=1.$
- If the question is "Has the PDE and condition a solution on the form of a multivalued function ? ", the answer is YES.

Comment: So few down-votes to my answer! Only two up to now. And no vote to delete my answer. I am surprised. Where are the proponents of the classic line, still on holidays?